# Creating folder in bucket google cloud storage using php

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am very new to the google cloud storage.

I want to create folder in bucket using php coding. I have searched a quite few sites and on 1 i saw it was written:

"Creating a folder inside a bucket will create a placeholder object named after the directory, has no data content and the mimetype application/x-directory. Directory placeholder objects created in Google Storage Manager are ​not supported."

I could not understand what it is trying to say. How can i create folder please help me out. I tried using the following code:

```
$req = new Google_HttpRequest("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/bucket/myfoldertrial");
$req->setRequestHeaders(array(
'x-goog-project-id' => 21212,
'x-goog-acl' => 'public-read',
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-directory'
));
$req->setRequestMethod('PUT');
$req->setPostBody('myfoldertrial');
```

I am using the API from following link:

[Google API for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

Please help me out creating folder using PHP.

Comment: Quick: You don't create folders, you just store files in paths so you send the filename like "folder/file" which will appear as a "folder" in the Buckets GUI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably don't actually need to create a folder.

Google Storage isn't a tree structure like your operating system's filesystem uses, all Objects are stored in buckets at the top level. However you can give an Object a name with slashes in it, so it will kind of look like it is in a folder - `Users/username/docs/2012/09/21/activity.csv` is a perfectly good name for an Object and doesn't need any supporting folders.

Once you've got Objects with this sort of scheme in place, you can list them as if you were viewing the contents of a folder with the `delimiter` and `prefix` parameters as per [these docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list).

So if you only wanted to create `myfoldertrial` so you could upload `example.png` into it, there's no need to create the folder, you can just upload straight to `myfoldertrial/example.png`.

Comment: so do u mean to say that there is no way to create folders using php??

Comment: I'm not saying that it can't be done, I'm mainly asking why you want to do it. There _might_ be some good reason that you'd want to create a folder, but they don't really exist the same way you'd be used to directories on your own computer, so it's worth taking a bit of time to stop and think about whether you actually need it.

Comment: I got your point. I will try it out. Till then Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, in a CMS, you need to create a directory first before able to upload file into it, so the mouse click can trigger an event to take the path as the base folder, then do a batch upload.

It's a file browser, they say.

This code below might help.

```
<?php

$privateKeyFile = '{{full/path/to/*.p12}}';
$newDirectory = '{{path/of/new/directory/}}'; // remember to end it with a slash.

/**
 * Authentication
 */
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Create a new folder');
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control');
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
if (!file_exists($privateKeyFile)) {
    die('missing the location of primary key file, given: ' . $privateKeyFile);
}
$key = file_get_contents($privateKeyFile);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $clientEmailAddress
        , $scopes
        , $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

/**
 * Creating Folder
 */
try {
    /* create empty file that acts as folder */
    $postBody = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
    $postBody->setName($newDirectory);
    $postBody->setSize(0);

    $created = $service->objects->insert($bucketName, $postBody, array(
        'name' => $newDirectory,
        'uploadType' => 'media',
        'projection' => 'full',
        'data' => '',
    ));
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage() . "\n<pre>";
    print_r($ex->getTraceAsString());
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
}

echo 'EOF';
```

Comment: Strange, I cannot get it to work. I'm trying to create a folder named `something` - an object is created but it's not a folder but a file with type set to `application/json; charset=UTF-8` (yes, I'm setting `application/x-directory`) and its content is `{"contentType":"application\/x-directory","name":"something","size":0}`. My code is the same as in your `try` clause but the authentication is different.

Comment: Try "something/" , with slash at the end

Comment: I was just about to write a new answer stating that a **slash at the end is needed** AND the 3rd parameter of `insert()` **must contain** field `data` set to a non-null value. Changing `servicePath`, using `setSize` and `setContentType` is **not needed**. If you change your answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: wow... I thought I've tried it, but thanks. I was digging into entire Classes but missed it. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create folder by providing it in a filepath when you are uploading it, 
i.e. your url should be https://storage.googleapis.com///?GoogleAccessId=id@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1410875751&Signature=SIGNATURE