# How can I create dynamic folder structure on google cloud storage using PHP?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Hey guys i am very new to google cloud storage..
I'm trying to use Google Cloud Storage in my PHP project- And I want to create a folder into bucket dynamically and sub folder into created folder.

How can I create it please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Tom,

I have tried this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527969/creating-folder-in-bucket-google-cloud-storage-using-php

Comment: And it's not working? What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: I have created a URL dynamically and fire it, It didn't work and even not given any error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create folders as accustomed in a file directory on a drive. In Cloud Storage everything are objects so even the folders. [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) is a full explanation of how directories work.

As everything is an Object you can create the folders as files are created only by ending the name with a slash '/' or with "$folder$"

Another way is when you create a file in your bucket just as part of the name put the folders. i.e. give the full name as /folder/subfolder/file

I'll write an example in PHP using the client library

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

/**
 * Upload a file.
 *
 * @param string $bucketName the name of your Google Cloud bucket.
 * @param string $objectName the name of the object.
 * @param string $source the path to the file to upload.
 *
 * @return Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface
 */
function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source, $folder)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $folder."/".$objectName
    ]);
    printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

If you want to use the REST API for doing this is important to escape the special characters on the names to be able to pass them as URLs

Comment: Hi Jose, Your code has solved my issue. and It's working perfectly.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If this code solved your problem please accept the answer.